# MySQL and PHP communication problem in Mac OS X 10.6.3

Tags: mysql, apache, macos, php

I followed [this](http://superfancy.net/coding/php-mysql-apache-in-mac-osx-leopard/) instruction but not worked for me. I just wanna install and config cakephp in my new MacBook Pro and that's why I'm tried to rename my php.ini.default to php.ini. Before that, I had no problem in communicating between my MySQL and Mac pre-installed PHP.

What's wrong with [that](http://superfancy.net/coding/php-mysql-apache-in-mac-osx-leopard/) instruction. ( specially "Getting MySQL and PHP to communicate" part )

BTW it's not permission problem or mysql.sock location I think. I checked them.

Please help me. 
Thanks

Comment: in my none cakephp applications I get : "Error connecting to mysql" and pages not load completely. And in cakephp application, In the first page ( after installtion ) I get " Cake is NOT able to connect to the database." error !!!

Comment: "...and Mac pre-installed PHP" - you mean you had php/mysql installations up and running on other machines before? Did you follow the same instructions and versions then?

Comment: My new mac have a pre-installed php and apache isntalled. I just uncomment LoadModule php5_module line in my httpd.conf. without renaming php.ini.default to php.ini everything is ok. my problem starts after renaming php.ini.default ! I need php.ini to configure correctly.

Comment: I said " ... pages not load completely." . I changed the value of short_open_tag to On and now just get the previous error: "Error connecting to mysql" !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's see if we can get a more detailed error message than "Error connecting to mysql".
What's the output of:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo 'mysql extension: ', extension_loaded('mysql') ? 'ok' : 'NOT ok', "<br />\n";
echo 'mysql_connect: ', function_exists('mysql_connect') ? 'ok' : 'NOT ok', "<br />\n";
mysql_connect('fill in', 'the right', 'values here') or die(mysql_error());
```

?

Comment: Error was: 
Warning: mysql_connect(): [2002] Permission denied (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) in /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysqltest.php on line 5 Warning: mysql_connect(): Permission denied in /Library/WebServer/Documents/mysqltest.php on line 5 Permission denied . it was 775 and I chmod it to 777 and problem solved. Many thanks. Thank you VolkerK

Comment: Wow, that was much quicker than anticipated. Good for you. :)